# Does JavaScript have the concept of l-value and r-value?

Tags: javascript, expression, ecmascript-5, referenceerror

In JavaScript, if you put some kind of expression on the left side of an assignment expression, the engine will throw a ReferenceError. For example,

```
// 'this' on the left side
this = window; // ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment
```

or

```
// function call expression on the left side
var a;
var fn = function() {return a};
a === fn(); // true
a = 1; // 1
fn() = 5; // ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment
```

or

```
var a;
a = 1; // 1
(a) = 2; // 2
(1, a) = 3; // ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment
```

My questions are:

1. Does JavaScript also have the concept of l-value and r-value as C?
2. Why function call expression can not appear on the left-hand of an assignment expression? In the above example, since `a === fn()`, what's the difference between `a = 5` and `fn() = 5`. I know that ES5 spec mandates this, but why is it designed like that?

Comment: `fn()` is an expression and not a variable reference, and you can't assign anything to that.

Comment: But the evaluation order is from left to right, if `fn()` is evaluated first, it will return `a`, since `fn() === a`. And `a` is a variable and can store values.

Comment: it returns the value of a, not a reference to the variable a

Comment: `a === fn()` doesn't mean they are the same memory location, and if it were, it would have COW semantics ... so, assignment to an expression is meaningless.

Comment: Hi @Patrick Evans, would you elaborate with an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [specification of assignments](https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-semantics-static-semantics-isvalidsimpleassignmenttarget), the following expressions are not valid as the target for an assignment:

```
this
Literal
ArrayLiteral
ObjectLiteral
FunctionExpression
ClassExpression
GeneratorExpression
RegularExpressionLiteral
TemplateLiteral
```

For example, the following assignments are invalid too:

```js
this    = "bar"; // this
"foo"   = "bar"; // Literal
/foo/   = "bar"; // RegularExpressionLiteral
["foo"] = "bar"; // ArrayLiteral
```

Answer (score 1):

The fact that `f()` can evaluate to a reference, in case you assign an object to `a` before calling function, doesn't change the fact that `f()` is an expression (same as for example `1+a`). And assignment can only be applied to a variable. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators#Assignment)

Comment: Hi @Kirill, thanks for the answer. `And assignment can only be applied to a variable.` I don't think this is accurate. You can definitely apply assignment to object property and array element, apart from variable.

Comment: @leslie.zhang pragmatically speaking, object properties and array elements  can be seen as variable references and thus can be used for assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Likewise, in the JavaScript language's world-view, "`this` is *(necessarily ...)* sacrosanct."

The *purpose,* and therefore the present value, of the `this` variable, is necessarily-protected from arbitrary modification by programs.

Likewise, "you simply *cannot* say that 'a function,' whatever it is, 'is equal to '5'."  (Quite obviously, one of these is a "function," and the other is "an integer constant," and so, "never the twain shall meet.")

The JavaScript interpreter, like every other language-interpreter on this planet, was designed and built using the same language-implementation strategies *(and tools ...)* employed by every other language that has ever been invented.